# Can't get result to display in page below input

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get the result to display on the html page, which is why i have it as an alert

```
<h1>Factorial Problem</h1>
<form name="frm1">
Enter any number :<input type="text" name="fact1"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="fact(frm1.fact1.value)">
```

here is the JavaScript

```
function fact(n){
    var m=1;
    while(n){
         m=m*n;
         n--;
    }
    alert("Factorial of given number :"+" "+ m);
}
```

Comment: Where do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: Are you doing anything to stop the form from being submitted and the page reloading?

Comment: Can you use JQuery or are you limited to vanilla Javascript?

Comment: next to the textbox or between the textbox and the calculate button. i don't think anything is stopping the page from reloading

Comment: im not opposed to jquery

Comment: @cSimms There should be. The default action of `input type="submit"` is, well ... submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an identifier in the DOM to inject the value with JS.

As an example, I toke you'r code and added a div with the id with the value 'result'.

Then with JS, we inject the value in the DOM on the click event of you'r button.

```
<h1>Factorial Problem</h1>
<form name="frm1">
Enter any number :<input type="text" name="fact1"><br><br>
<div id="result"></div>    
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="fact(frm1.fact1.value)">


function fact(n){
    var m=1;
    while(n){
         m=m*n;
         n--;
    }

    var el = document.getElementById('result'); 
    el.innerHTML = "Factorial of given number :"+" "+ m;
    // alert("Factorial of given number :"+" "+ m);
}
```

Comment: should be el.innerHTML instead of el.value

Comment: You should also include a description of what you've done. Just dumping code is never a good answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote but ill up vote since I think this is what he is asking for

Comment: Your code has the same problem as OP's. Please test your code, and you'll see.

Comment: @Teemu : can you be more specific ? I've added a description of my solution + the code  OP should have now his answer.

Comment: Umh ... Just test your code, or read j08691's or my comment below the question.

Comment: Got it, input type should be a button, not a submit.

Comment: Yes, that would be one solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <h1>Factorial Problem</h1>

   Enter any number :<input type="text" id="fact1"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="fact()">

   <p id="result"></p>
</body>



function fact(){
   var m=1;
   var n=document.getElementById("fact1").value;
   while(n){
      m=m*n;
      n--;
    }
    //alert("Factorial of given number :"+" "+ m);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=m;
 }
```